# How to select attributes from JSON to a python list

Tags: python, json, python-requests

From the JSON returned here: [https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements/aa563d0b-3695-c99c-b404-7be808106e31?format=json&api-version=1.2&limit=25&page={}](https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements/aa563d0b-3695-c99c-b404-7be808106e31?format=json&api-version=1.2&limit=25&page=%7B%7D)

I'm trying to be selective in which 'attributes' to stick in a list, with Python.
(Really just because I need to change the date format to work in csv, and don't know how to do it without having lists composed only of date data.)

Here trying to put only the 'date-from' attribute into my list:

```
date_from = []
            for a in data["data"]["plans"]:
                date_from.append(**a["attributes"]['date-from'])
```

I'm sorry for not showing the whole working program, as that's **very** long - a lot to get through to see that one line above that appends.

Anyway, I'm getting this error: *TypeError: append() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str*

How else would you suggest to do it?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `**` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `**` since the error says that the value in `a["attributes"]['date-from']` is a str not a map (dict)

```
date_from = []
for a in data["data"]["plans"]:
    date_from.append(a["attributes"]['date-from'])
```